# Unable to apply css style to span within list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, thymeleaf

So I have quite an interesting issue here. I'd assume it's something I'm just not aware of or there's a mistake/logical issue somewhere. Anyhow long story short I have a html code with a list that is produced by thymeleaf. The idea is to hide a checkbox button behind each list element, which makes it selectable and therefor gives me a quick and easy way to handle the data java's side.

Anyhow my issue however is with the styling of the selector  element.

I'm trying to change pointer/color when clicked on. I have added a class into the one span element that is used in my css file as follows. I have tried so many different ways and none of it ever applies it to any of the span elements within my css. However if I simply add style within the span element inside html it works fine. So my question here is, what could be the cause as to why it does not work with the css? Or is it simply something I don't understand yet or may have overlooked?

You can find the code below. Any help is much appreciated!

The one in question is

```css
    .minionInputData {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3cm;
}

.minionInputs p {
    display: inline-block;
    float: top;
    margin-left: 2cm;

}

.minionContent {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1cm;
}

.minionInputs {
   margin-bottom: 2cm;
}

.rolesTableContainer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.roles-table input[type=checkbox] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}


.rolesText {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 3px;
}

.roles-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
    background: blue;
}

.argsTableContainer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.arguments-table {
    /*margin: 0 0 0 auto;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.arguments {
    width: 100%;
}

.arguments table {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

.arguments td {
    padding: 8px;
    border-style:outset;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    height: 100%;
}

.arguments td input{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    font-size:26px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    text-align: center;
}

.arguments tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #ffffcc;
}

.arguments tr:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.addrowbutton {
    float: right;
    top: 200px;
}

/*.addallarguments {
  background: #ff0000;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #3f219e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #3f219e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #3f219e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000, #3f219e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000, #3f219e);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.addallarguments:hover {
  background: #311ebd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #311ebd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #311ebd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #311ebd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #311ebd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #311ebd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.confirmButtons{
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
}*/

.confirmButtons input{

 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #899599;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #899599;
 box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #899599;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #a1a1a1));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #a1a1a1 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #a1a1a1 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #a1a1a1 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #a1a1a1 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ededed 5%, #a1a1a1 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#a1a1a1',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#ededed;
 -moz-border-radius:13px;
 -webkit-border-radius:13px;
 border-radius:13px;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#121212;
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:16px 25px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #e1e2ed;
}

.confirmButtons input:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #a1a1a1), color-stop(1, #ededed));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1 5%, #ededed 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1 5%, #ededed 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1 5%, #ededed 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #a1a1a1 5%, #ededed 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #a1a1a1 5%, #ededed 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a1a1a1', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#a1a1a1;
}

.confirmButtons input:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Minions configurations</title>
    <h1 align="center">Minion configuration</h1>
</head>

<body background="../static/images/MainBackground.jpg" th:background="@{images/MainBackground.jpg}">

<div id="allRolesContent">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/minions}" th:object="${selectedRole}" method="post">
        <select id="allRoles" th:field="*{roleName}">
            <option th:each="roleObj : ${allMinionRoles}"
                    th:value="${roleObj.getRoleName()}"
                    th:text="${roleObj.getRoleName()}">ROLES
            </option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="submit" name="addRole" value="Add Formula" /></p>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="minionForm" class="minionForm">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/minions.css" th:href="@{css/minions.css}"/>
    <script src="../static/js/buttons.js" th:src="@{js/buttons.js}"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/PageFunctions" th:src="@{js/PageFunctions}"></script>
    <div id="minionContent" class="minionContent">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/minions}" th:object="${minions}" method="post">
            <div id="minionInputs" class="minionInputs">
                <p>Configuration Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" th:required="required"/></p>
                <p>Enironment(eg LABOR): <input type="text" th:field="*{env}" th:required="required"/></p>
            </div>
            <div class="rolesTableContainer">
                <div class="roles-table">
                    <ul>
                        <li style="list-style-type: none;" th:each="role : ${currentMinionRoles}">
                            <label th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}">
                                <span class="rolesText" th:text="test">ROLE</span>
                                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}"/>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"/>
                    <button name="moveUP" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
                    <button name="moveDown" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="argsTableContainer">
                <div class="arguments-table">
                    <table id="argsTable" class="arguments">
                        <h1 align="center">Arguments list</h1>
                        <input class="addrowbutton" type="submit" name="add" value="Add Argument" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" onclick="addRow('argsTable','argumentTr')"
                               th:onclick="'addRow(\'argsTable\',\'argumentTr\');'"/>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Argument Name</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="argumentTr" th:each="argument : *{arguments}">
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" th:value="${argument.argName}" id="argName" name="argName"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" th:value="${argument.value}" id="value" name="value"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="confirmButtonsContainer">
                <div class="confirmButtons">
                    <input type="submit" name="saveAll" value="Save Configuration" />
                    <input type="submit" name="updateConf" value="Update Configuration"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest not to write a testimony keep your question simple....

Comment: Please include the actual HTML output rather than the server side code before it gets processed by the browser. As of now we can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've updated the full code. It seems That rolesText class is applied as per usual , but for some reason the .roles-table class does not work and the color is not applied on change

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking for something like this, cus I could not understand quite clear. I made a simple example with `jQuery`. So, if your list is checked, it will add another class to that `span`, and this `span` will take `style` from `stylesheet` file, not just if you add inline style.

P.S, you could do this with css too, without `jQuery`, but I did not change your code structure, so I had to do a simple demo with jQuery.

Hope this helps you!

```js
$("input").on("change", function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var checkboxElement = _this.parent().find(".rolesText");
  
 if(_this.is(':checked')) {
     checkboxElement.addClass("checked");
   }
 else {
     checkboxElement.removeClass("checked");
   } 
})
```

```css
.roles-table input[type=checkbox] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}

.rolesText {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.rolesText.checked {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.roles-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rolesTableContainer">
        <div class="roles-table">
            <ul>
                <li style="list-style-type: none;" th:each="role : ${currentMinionRoles}">
                    <label th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}">
                        <span class="rolesText" th:text="${role.getRoleName()}">Role Name Here</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}"/>
                    </label>
                </li>
                 <li style="list-style-type: none;" th:each="role : ${currentMinionRoles}">
                    <label th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}">
                        <span class="rolesText" th:text="${role.getRoleName()}">Role Name Here</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}"/>
                    </label>
                </li>
                 <li style="list-style-type: none;" th:each="role : ${currentMinionRoles}">
                    <label th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}">
                        <span class="rolesText" th:text="${role.getRoleName()}">Role Name Here</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}"/>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"/>
            <button name="moveUP" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
            <button name="moveDown" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is a fair solution! Thanks for the quick reply. I'm still little curious why is the css never applied to my element? That was the main issue that I have. Adding it inside <span> with style="..." works fine however?

Comment: @Shad3less, make sure if span has that class, in that case to apply css, otherwise it won't work. Is your website online? Maybe I could inspect and help you with your issue.

Comment: I'm clearly making a mistake somewhere cause it does not accept my css with the class included. Let me see if I can send you the 2 source files.

Answer (score 0):

Cascading styles sheets are as they sound - cascading so you cannot go backwards or upwards, only forwards and downwards.  If you want to style something if the checkbox is checked, place it *after* the checkbox and use a sibling selector - either `+` or `~`:

```css
.roles-table input[type=checkbox] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
}

.rolesText {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.roles-table input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
  /* this means the span that directly follows a checked input */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: blue;
}


/* if you need the span to appear first, use the following */

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label>span {
  order: 1;
}

label>input {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="rolesTableContainer">
  <div class="roles-table">
    <ul>
      <li style="list-style-type: none;" th:each="role : ${currentMinionRoles}">
        <label th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}">
          <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{roleName}" th:value="${role.getRoleName()}"/>
          <span class="rolesText" th:text="${role.getRoleName()}">test</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" name="remove" value="Remove" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
    <button name="moveUP" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">&ShortUpArrow;</button>
    <button name="moveDown" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">&ShortDownArrow;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay seems that I have a logical error elsewhere. Because clearly it works here, but does not work in my full code. Let me update it into the full code snippet I have. Perhaps someone can find the issue.